# Is there a simple way to add dollar signs to a column?

Tags: r, format

Is there a simple way to add dollar signs to a column that I have? I can't find any way within `format()` other than just decimals, commas, etc.. For example, I have:

```
numbers <- data.frame(x1 = 1:4, x5 = 11:14, x6 = 21:24, y = 31:34)
```

How can I format `numbers$y` to have dollar signs in front of it?

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to go supreme overkill and keep the numerics on the column, but have them print with a dollar sign, you could write a print method.

```
class(numbers$y) <- "dollar"
format.dollar <- function(x, ...) paste0("$", unclass(x))
as.data.frame.dollar <- base:::as.data.frame.factor
```

Now it prints with the dollar signs ...

```
numbers
#   x1 x5 x6   y
# 1  1 11 21 $31
# 2  2 12 22 $32
# 3  3 13 23 $33
# 4  4 14 24 $34
```

... but the column is still numeric.

```
numbers$y[]
# [1] 31 32 33 34
```

Comment: lol.. thanks.. but I'm going to just opt for doing this after I'm all done sorting my data :)

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers$y<-paste("$",numbers$y)
```

Will do it nicely.  But beware, it is then treated as text and not a number

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
numbers$y <- paste0('$', numbers$y)
```

Note that you should only do this once you're done processing this column -- after you add the dollar sign it will be a chr and not eligible for numerical computations.

To undo this step, you can use:

```
as.numeric(substring(text = numbers$y, first = 2))
```

For future reference, `paste0(...)` is simply a shortcut for `paste(..., sep="")`. Since `paste` defaults to a space separation.

Answer (score 0):

I like `{tidyr}` for its ease of use:

```r
data.frame(x1 = 1:4, x5 = 11:14, x6 = 21:24, y = 31:34, unit = "$") %>% 
  tidyr::unite_("y2", c("unit", "y"), sep = "", remove = TRUE)
```