# Waterfall plot - how to format labels ($xx.xx)

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, bar-chart, currency-formatting

Trying to make a waterfall chart using the Waterfalls package (seemed like the easiest solution).
I'm quite new to R and ggplot (and have been browsing stackoverflow for help).

I'd like to format the labels as $xx.xx.

Here's the data:

| Factors | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Start | 119.19 |
| Differential A | -25.4 |
| Move | -0.832 |
| EQ | -5.70 |
| Differential (Premium) | 4.93 |
| Transportation | -7.37 |

I can get a plot with this:

```
waterfall(wf, calc_total=TRUE, rect_width=.4, fill_by_sign=TRUE, total_rect_color="grey", rect_border=NA) + labs(y="Cost", title ="Waterfall", x=NULL)
```

[image: Basic plot]

1. If I try to add a dollar sign to the labels, it doesn't recognize "Cost".

```
waterfall(wf, calc_total=TRUE, rect_width=.4, fill_by_sign=TRUE, total_rect_color="grey", rect_border=NA, rect_text_labels=dollar(Cost)) + labs(y="Cost", title ="Waterfall", x=NULL)
```

`Error: object 'Cost' not found`

2. Trying to round the labels to 2 decimal places gives me the same issue with referring to "Cost".

```
waterfall(wf, calc_total=TRUE, rect_width=.4, fill_by_sign=TRUE, total_rect_color="grey", rect_border=NA) + labs(y="Cost", title ="Waterfall", x=NULL) + geom_text(aes(label = round(Cost, digits = 4)))
```

```
Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 23rd layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'Cost' not found
```

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward but I think it may be an issue with a general lack of knowledge of R.

Comment: Welcome, @zxcvfi, to Stack Overflow. Lots of helpful folks here. It'll help to know that standard (perhaps even strict) practice here is to ask only one question at a time (for search ability). But here's a start re: dollar signs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772887/is-there-a-simple-way-to-add-dollar-signs-to-a-column

Comment: Duly noted! Thanks.

Comment: A glance at the `?waterfall` help page show that it takes a parameter `rect_text_labels` described as *"a character vector of the same length as values that are placed on the rectangles"*. So I'd try something like adding `rect_text_labels = scales::dollar_format()(wf$Cost)` as an argument.

Comment: @GregorThomas Beautiful! I can't accept or upvote your comment as a new user, but this is great. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't test because I don't have the package installed, but with that confirmation I'll post it as an answer so we can mark your question resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?waterfall` help page shows that it takes a parameter,

> `rect_text_labels`
>
> a character vector of the same length as values that are placed on the rectangles.

So try adding `rect_text_labels = scales::dollar_format()(wf$Cost)` as an argument to the `waterfall` call.

Comment: The only thing left is that the Total label doesn't round to 2 decimal places like all the other labels. I followed your lead and checked out ?waterfalls and assume it has to do with the calc_total argument, but I don't know how to manipulate this.

Comment: Use the `total_rect_text` argument, perhaps `total_rect_text = scales::dollar_format()(sum(wf$cost))`

Comment: YES! Thank you again.